# python nltk regex_tokenize with using `?:` behaves different ways

Tags: python, nltk, python-re

why in

```py
text = 'That U.S.A. poster-print costs $12.40...'

pattern = r'''(?:[A-Z]\.)+'''

nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern)
# result: ['U.S.A.']

pattern = r'''([A-Z]\.)+'''. # removed ?:

nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern)
# result: ['A.']
```

I am getting different results?
I don't understand why `?:` affects to resulting